# Value of a function involving integration at a particular point

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $y = y(x) $ satisfy the equation 
$$y(x) + \int_1^x{y(t)}dt = x^2$$ then find the value of y(e).

My attempt: I tried to differentiate the given expression and reached to the following:
$$y'(x) + y(x) = 2x$$I don't have any clue how to find the value of $y(e)$ from here. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You differentiated correctly. The expression you got after that, is called a "*differential equation*" and depending on its form, one can be solved in different ways.

A straight forward and common way to solve such a linear ordinary differential equation, is multiplying both sides by $e^x$, since one can see the following pattern :

$$y'(x) + y(x) = 2x \Leftrightarrow e^xy'(x)  + e^xy(x) = 2e^xx \Rightarrow [e^xy(x)]'=2e^xx \Rightarrow $$

$$\int[e^xy(x)]'dx=\int2e^xxdx \Rightarrow e^xy(x)= 2e^x(x-1) + c_1$$

To find the constant $c_1$, check your initial equation. Plugging $x=1$ will give you :

$$y(1) + \int_1^1y(t)dt=1 \Rightarrow y(1)=1$$

This means that :

$$y(1)=c_1\cdot e^{-1}\Rightarrow c_1 = e$$

So, the final solution is :

$$y(x) = 2(x-1) +\frac{e}{e^x}$$

and for $x=e$  :

$$y(e) = 2(e-1) + \frac{e}{e^e}=2(e-1) + e^{1-e}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is a linear ODE. The solution is given as (homogeneouse+linear function ansatz for particular solution)

$$y(x)= c_1\exp(-x)+2x-2.$$

Plug this into the original equation and determine the value of $c_1$. Then finally use $x=e$ and determine $y(e)$.